# .Net Core console app publish not creating any files inside publish folder

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, console-application

I have a console app in .net core 2.2. I am trying to publish it through Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise(version 15.9.14) by right click project and click on Publish option.

**The problem** is its showing publish successful, **but no files are created inside the publish folder.**

I have tried through command line but there also no files are created.

Command: `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release`

Visual Studio Publish Configuration:

[image]

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong here. And if no, then how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Try from commandline `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release -o c:\windows\temp` and show the console output.

Comment: I am getting error `NU1605: Detected package downgrade` for many system files because of log4net nuget package. Maybe this is the reason for not publishing?

Comment: How to solve this error? I've tried adding `<NoWarn>` in `<PropertyGroup>`, but still getting the error.

Comment: Is it a core or framework project? and what versions?

Comment: The console app is a core project targeting .net core 2.2. The log4net(version 2.0.8) is inside a .net standard 2.0 project. The standard project is being referred from the console app.

Comment: Hhmm, that should be a painless setup and i am using the same log4net 2.0.8 in many projects without any pain. But you must have a NuGet/Reference that expect a higher version than normal. Can you update your question with the compiler output where the errors i listed.